# estimate of the variance of estimator for the effect of a predictor variable in a multiple linear regression model in R

Tags: r, regression, lm

```
    bweight   gestwks            hyp sex    

1    2974 38.5200004577637       0 female          
2    3270 NA                     0 male            
3    2620 38.150001525878899     0 female          
4    3751 39.799999237060497     0 male            
5    3200 38.889999389648402     1 male           
6    3673 40.970001220703097     0 female
```

bweight=baby weight

gestwks=gestation period in week

hyp=presence of maternal hypertension

sex=sex of baby

I haven this sample , and I have created a multiple linear regression model with the following code:

```
lm2 = lm(bweight ~ gestwks + hyp + male)
```

Where male and female is a vector of 1's for the male and 0's for the females.

How do I find the unbiased estimate of the variance of the errors sigma^2? Is the code:

```
summary(lm2)$sigma^2
```

going to give me the answer i'm looking for?

Also, how do I find the estimate of the variance of estimator for the effect of hypertension.

So, say I have that the presence of hypertension affects the baby's weight with -200 (i.e 1 unit increase in hypertension causes the average weight to decrease in 200). What would be the estimate of the variance of estimators for the effect of hypertension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example data:

```
df = structure(list(bweight = c(2974L, 3270L, 2620L, 3751L, 3200L, 
3673L), gestwks = c(38.5200004577637, NA, 38.1500015258789, 39.7999992370605, 
38.8899993896484, 40.9700012207031), hyp = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L), sex = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("female", 
"male"), class = "factor"), male = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")

df$male = as.numeric(df$sex=="male")
lm2 = lm(bweight ~ gestwks + hyp + male,data=df)
```

What you want is the variance-covariance matrix:

```
vcov(lm2)
            (Intercept)     gestwks         hyp       male
(Intercept)   8615153.6 -219476.110 -199723.227 119995.418
gestwks       -219476.1    5596.976    5093.248  -3283.549
hyp           -199723.2    5093.248   57215.841 -29278.523
male           119995.4   -3283.549  -29278.523  36980.334
```

The diagonal is the variance of each estimator, and if you take the square root, you get the standard error shown with summary:

```
sqrt(diag(vcov(lm2)))
(Intercept)     gestwks         hyp        male 
 2935.15819    74.81294   239.19833   192.30271 

summary(lm2)

Call:
lm(formula = bweight ~ gestwks + hyp + male, data = df)

Residuals:
         1          3          4          5          6 
 1.218e+02 -1.058e+02  0.000e+00  7.105e-15 -1.598e+01 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -10304.13    2935.16  -3.511    0.177
gestwks        341.55      74.81   4.565    0.137
hyp           -240.19     239.20  -1.004    0.499
male           461.63     192.30   2.401    0.251
```

Comment: the square root of the intercept is 2935.15819 and the standard error is 2935.16. I don't get it. Why are they equal?

Comment: in the summary function, it's rounded up. do coefficients(summary(lm2))